# How to pass an array of a class from a helper to an apex controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, controller, lightning, array

I have created a class with several fields like this:

```
    public class Tier{
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Name {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public integer Min {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public integer Max {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public Decimal Amount {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public integer cnt {get; set;} 
}
```

This is made in the apex controller and linked to a lightning component.

The lightning component has an attribute wich contains multiple "Tiers" as an array.

```
<aura:attribute name="tiers" type="StaffelPricingController.tier[]"/>
```

Than after editing it should be send back to the apex controller class for further processing like this:

```
    changeTiers : function(component){
    var tiers = component.get("v.tiers");
    var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
    var action = component.get("c.getSave");
    action.setParams({
        "recordId": recordId,
        "tiers": tiers
    })
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

after this I want to have the list of tiers available for editing in apex so I did this:

```
public static string getSave (list<tier> tiers, string recordId){
//do some stuf here and return a string
}
```

now the value of tiers is not the correct type for processing, it seems to come in like some sort of JSON string that I can't process with de deserialize options.

Does anyone have any idea how te get a propper list of class back from a lightning component?

any help is appreciated, hints, tips, whatever

Comment: The string I'm getting back looks like this:
({cnt=1, Name=-}, {cnt=2, Name=-}, {cnt=3, Name=-}, {cnt=4, Name=-})

Comment: If I stringify it first it looks like this: [{"cnt":1,"Name":"-"},{"cnt":2,"Name":"-"},{"cnt":3,"Name":"-"}]
Is there a way I can process it like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be simply be able to use the list .

Do not try to DeSerialize ,its already deserialized and you can consume the list as it is

```
public static string getSave (list<tier> tiers, string recordId){
  //do some stuf here and return a string
  for(StaffelPricingController.tier t:tiers){

  }
}
```

Comment: I'm affraid it wasn't.  
A propper list looks like this:  
(Tier:[Amount=null, Max=null, Min=null, Name=-, cnt=1], Tier:[Amount=null, Max=null, Min=null, Name=-, cnt=2], Tier:[Amount=null, Max=null, Min=null, Name=-, cnt=3])
  
  
I finaly made it work by using the "Stringify" command in JAVA to create the propper JSON than I used this:
  
tier[] records = (tier[])JSON.deserialize(tiers, List<tier>.class);

Comment: Aura Enabled class should have done for you automatically .Annotating a class with auraenabled is meant to be doing this ,if not then i would log a case with SFDC.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I'm having an issue like this, it gives no compile errors. But getting  FATAL_ERROR System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error: 1996097431-19512 (-1753594556) (-1753594556)  when it tries to loop the wrapper class.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the `callback` of your action in the JS controller.

```
changeTiers : function(component){
  var tiers = component.get("v.tiers");
  var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
  var action = component.get("c.getSave");
  action.setParams({
      "recordId": recordId,
      "tiers": tiers
  });

  action.setCallBack(this, function(a){
    if(a.getState() === 'SUCCESS'){
      component.set('v.result', a.getReturnValue());
      // a.getReturnValue() is the value returned from the apex class
    }

  });

  $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm) is a link to the docs.